# How to get a value that I set in a method like onClick in java?

Tags: java, android

I setted (by setter) a value in a method what is like onClick() method in a class named MyketUpdater.
But when I want to get it (by getter) in my MainActivity and show it by a toast it gives me false value and not that I setted. But when I get it in onClick of my TextView and toast it in MainActivity, it gives me true value and what I want and set before.

Here is my MyketUpdater Class:

```
public class MyketUpdater {

    private Context context;
    private String tag;
    private MyketSupportHelper mMyketHelper;
    public boolean isServiceConnected;
    public int resultOfChecking;
    public static final int ERROR_IN_MYKET_SERVICE = 0;
    public static final int UPDATE_AVAILABLE_MYKET = 1;
    public static final int UP_TO_DATA_MYKET = 2;
    private String updateDesc = null;

    public MyketUpdater(Context context, String tag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void connectService() {
        Log.d("dd", "Creating helper.");
        mMyketHelper = new MyketSupportHelper(context);
        // Enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
        mMyketHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
        Log.d("dd", "Starting setup.");

        mMyketHelper.startSetup(new MyketSupportHelper.OnMyketSetupFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyketSetupFinished(MyketResult result) {
                Log.d("dd", "Setup finished.");
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Here i set that value by setter
                    setServiceConnected(false);
                    return;
                }
                // Here i set that value by setter
                setServiceConnected(true);
                mMyketHelper.getAppUpdateStateAsync(mCheckAppUpdateListener);
            }
        });
    }

    private MyketSupportHelper.CheckAppUpdateListener mCheckAppUpdateListener = new MyketSupportHelper
            .CheckAppUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckAppUpdateFinished(MyketResult result, Update update) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                setResultOfChecking(ERROR_IN_MYKET_SERVICE);
                return;
            }

            if (update.isUpdateAvailable()) {
                setResultOfChecking(UPDATE_AVAILABLE_MYKET);
            } else {
                setResultOfChecking(UP_TO_DATA_MYKET);
            }
        }
    };


    public void setServiceConnected(boolean serviceConnected) {
        isServiceConnected = serviceConnected;
    }

    public boolean getServiceConnected() {
        return isServiceConnected;
    }

    public int getResultOfChecking() {
        return resultOfChecking;
    }

    public void setResultOfChecking(int resultOfChecking) {
        this.resultOfChecking = resultOfChecking;
    }
}
```

And here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyketSupportHelper mMyketHelper;

    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        final MyketUpdater myketUpdater = new MyketUpdater(MainActivity.this, "sh");
        myketUpdater.connectService();

        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Here toast me the true values
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myketUpdater.getServiceConnected() + "\n" + myketUpdater.getResultOfChecking(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Here toast me the False values
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myketUpdater.getServiceConnected() + "\n" + myketUpdater.getResultOfChecking(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Comment: Hi, I've added an answer explaining your issue and how you could solve said issue. Mark it as correct if it works (or feel free to add a comment if you have any doubts/issues). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the `onClickListener`.

The `connectService` method has an asynchronous call `mMyketHelper.startSetup` which set's the value for `isServiceConnected`. It's true value can only be set once it's callback `onMyketSetupFinished` executes.

If you wish to get the `isServiceConnected` value immediately after the value has been set, create an interface and use a callback to get the value.

Something along the following lines should work,

**Create your callback interface**

```
interface MyketCustomCallback {
    void myketServiceComplete(Boolean isServiceConnected);
}
```

**Create your function as follows**

```
    public void connectService(final MyketCustomCallback callback) {
        Log.d("dd", "Creating helper.");
        mMyketHelper = new MyketSupportHelper(context);
        // Enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
        mMyketHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener will be called once setup completes.
        Log.d("dd", "Starting setup.");

        mMyketHelper.startSetup(new MyketSupportHelper.OnMyketSetupFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyketSetupFinished(MyketResult result) {
                Log.d("dd", "Setup finished.");
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Here i set that value by setter
                    setServiceConnected(false);
                    callback.myketServiceComplete(false);
                    return;
                }
                // Here i set that value by setter
                setServiceConnected(true);
                callback.myketServiceComplete(true);
                mMyketHelper.getAppUpdateStateAsync(mCheckAppUpdateListener);
            }
        });
    }
```

**You can then call the function in the main method as follows**

```
myketUpdater.connectService(new MyketCustomCallback() {
            @Override
            public void myketServiceComplete(Boolean isServiceConnected) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, isServiceConnected.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. but it has some mistakes in your code. For example you must declare myketCustomCallback to final and use myketServiceComplete instead isServiceConnected. But thanks a lot again!

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I've updated the answer. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyketSupportHelper mMyketHelper;
    private MyketUpdater myketUpdater;
    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        myketUpdater = new MyketUpdater(MainActivity.this, "sh");
        myketUpdater.connectService();

        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Here toast me the true values
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myketUpdater.getServiceConnected() + "\n" + myketUpdater.getResultOfChecking(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Here toast me the False values
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myketUpdater.getServiceConnected() + "\n" + myketUpdater.getResultOfChecking(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```